# jQuery sum table cells per table row

Tags: jquery

I'd like to form a sum of a table where a value exist and display them in a seperate td.

The table I'm working with has some content which aren't numbers and the numbers of table rows are variable.

```
names        | val 1 | val 2  | val n | val n+1 | sum
name 1       | 0,00  |  12,00 | -3,00 | 1,00    |
another name | 1,00  |   1,00 |  1,00 | 0,00    |
name x       | 1,00  | no int |  2,00 | 0,00    |
```

each td with a value to sum looks like `<td> some text <span class="tosum"> 1,00 </span></td>`.
the sum column looks like `<td class="finalsum"></td>` and is empty from the beginning.

Since I'm able to focus on elements with `.tosum` per row I was thinking about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(){
    sumTable();
});

function sumTable(){
    var sum = 0;
    
    $("tr").each(function(){
        sum += parseFloat($(this).find(".tosum").text().replace(',', '.'));
        $(this).find("td.finalsum").text(sum);
    
        //console.log($(this).find(".tosum").text() + " // ");

    });
}
```

trying to add the values causes NaN in the sum row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that the syntax for your document.ready handler is incorrect. It should be `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code here */ });`

With regard to the issue of summing the rows, you need two loops. One through all th `tr` elements and another through the target `td` within it. Then you can simply parse the text values to floats after replacing the `,` characters with `.` and add to the running total. In addition you should update `.totalsum` after the loop through the `td`. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  sumTable();
});

function sumTable() {
  $("tr").each((_, tr) => {  
    let sum = 0, $tr = $(tr);
    $tr.children('td:not(:first, .finalsum)').each((_, td) => {
      sum += parseFloat($(td).find('.tosum').text().replace(',', '.')) || 0;    
    });
    $tr.children('.finalsum').text(sum);
  });
}
```

```css
.finalsum { 
  text-align: right; 
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>names</td>
    <td>val 1</td>
    <td>val 2</td>
    <td>val n</td>
    <td>val n+1</td>
    <td>sum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name 1</td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">0,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">12,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">-3,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">1,00</span></td>
    <td class="finalsum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another name</td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">1,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">1,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">1,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">0,00</span></td>
    <td class="finalsum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name x</td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">1,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">no int</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">2,00</span></td>
    <td>some text <span class="tosum">0,00</span></td>
    <td class="finalsum"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I'm trying to understand what you posted. One note, sorry for the missunderstanding, within the span `tosum` are only values, for the no int value it looks something like this: `<td>no int <span class="tosum"></span></td>` so the class is empty then

Comment: That's fine - the logic will ignore any value which cannot be parsed to a floating point number, ie. whether the span is empty or contains alpha characters

Comment: ah ok, i see. I try to implement your code but some things don't seem to work out as they should. I try to console.log the sum once it should be ready but for some reason the values don't add up. Trying to set the value or a random text for the finalsum doesn't work either.

Comment: my bad, I was looking at the wrong row when trying to add everything up and check the values. thank you very much for your time and help!